# Javascript setInterval is not defined

Tags: javascript, window, undefined

**setInterval is not defined**

```
API.onServerEventTrigger.connect(function(eventName, args) {
  switch (eventName) {
    case "arrest":
      jail = true;
      counter = args[0];
      API.sendChatMessage("Mark 1");
      var myVar = setInterval(lowerCounter, 1000);
      API.sendChatMessage("Mark 2");
      break;
  }
});

function lowerCounter() {
  counter--;
  API.sendChatMessage("Mark 3");
}
```

I got this error `ReferenceError: setInterval is not defined`
and I don't know what is wrong.

The compiler reach and send the message `Mark 1`, but after that it fails.
I tried with `window.setInterval` and then says that window is not defined.

Comment: Hi, you need to add context as to where  this error is happening. It seems that it is not happening in a browser where the window and setInterval functions exists. If this is server side javascript, like node.js you may need to call a different function for a timed loop.

Comment: The code is working on client-side. I script a GTA V server. I think that's the error...

Answer (score 0):

you did mistake in the function.If function throws any error then setInterval also won't defined.Inside the function you used counter variable.But you did not defined properly.Make it as global variable and pass to that function parameter.

```
function lowerCounter() {
  counter--; //  error
  API.sendChatMessage("Mark 3");
}
```

Comment: counter variable is defined as global.